# Datatables searching date using month names

Tags: datatables

I have this problem, I stored date on mysql using 'yyyy-mm-dd' format, and then I'm using datatables to display the date, I want searching the date I'm displayed using month names like January, February etc. but datatables search only allow me search using month number, any solution ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this date format for display in data

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%Y-%M-%d')as showdate from table
```

then you can search by month name

Comment: so you mean I have to use that query on my datatables ssp to display the date ? I 'll try it and I'll let you know

Comment: for ssp try this
`array( 'db' => 'date',   'dt' => 3, 'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
        return date('Y-F-d',strtotime($d));
        })`